# Azure multiple subscriptions network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm currently stuck with designing my Azure environments.
What i would like to have is multiple Azure subscriptions that work togheter in a private network with Active directory on the different subscriptions that are synced.

Imagine the following scenario:
I've got two developers, who each have an own Azure Subscription (free with msdn) on which they develop their software.

When they finished the code, they will do a checkin to a visualstudio online and a build server on a second azure subscription will build the code.

When everything is ok, the code will be deployed on a VM in a third subscription.

All this would need to work with synced active directory's and in a private network.
This means that if their is a website created in the thrid subscription, it would only be accesible from a VM in subscription 1 or 2

So as resume:
1 subscription for the developer to developer code (visual studio, AD, sql, ...)
1 subscription for building the code of the developer
1 subscription for collect all the code and test the software (AD, SQL, website, ...)

Only subscription 1 should be able to access VM's, websites, ... in subscription 2 or 3.

Could any of you advise how I should set up the Virtual network, VPN, ...? Or maybe is just not possible?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Today's Virtual Network feature does not let you span data center regions, subscriptions, etc. as far as I know, sorry!

I'm sure people are looking at what it would take to support this sort of scenario someday.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to look at Azure **VNet-to-VNet VPN gateway**. It works fine through different regions and Azure subscriptions.